# How to conclude from Upgrade Status module if my website is ready to be upgraded from 9 to 10 in command line?

Tags: 9, upgrading

How to conclude from [Upgrade Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) module if my website is ready to be upgraded from 9 to 10 in **command line**?

From [the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) I understand that I should run either of these commands:

- `vendor/bin/drush upgrade_status:analyze (us-a) --all`
- `vendor/bin/drush upgrade_status:checkstyle (us-cs) --all`

Is that correct or at least, Would you use more particular arguments?

My question is general and principal but my personal case is a primarily core 9.5.9 website with [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect), [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) and [Asset Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/asset_injector) contrib modules.

Comment: To be clear the `(us-a)` and `(us-cs)` are the shortcut names for each subcommand. You would use `upgrade_status:analyze` or `us-a`, but not both. They are equivalent. This is how Drush works. That isn't particular to upgrade_status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, `upgrade_status:analyze` produces ASCII style output whereas `upgrade_status:checkstyle` produces XML. That choice is your preference.

You can pass each command a list of projects to analyze, or use any of these options:

```
  --all                Analyze all projects.                                                                     
  --skip-existing      Return results from a previous scan of a project if available, otherwise start a new one. 
  --ignore-uninstalled Ignore uninstalled projects.                                                              
  --ignore-contrib     Ignore contributed projects.                                                              
  --ignore-custom      Ignore custom projects.
```

As you are using `--all` that should check every project, every time you execute the command.

Comment: For a more specific answer you will have to ask a specific question.